# Keyboard Shortcut does not make it to CefSharp Browser Control

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, cefsharp

I have a cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser that loads various web pages for our WPF application.
One of these web pages handles keyboard shortcuts like (Alt+S and Alt+C). If the page is called from an external browser these shortcuts work as expected.
But when the shortcuts are used in the cefSharp:ChromiusWebBrowser Control they don't work.

I tried to figure out whether the Shortcuts get handled by the UserControl that contains the browser control by using

```
private bool _altKeyPressed = false;
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (_altKeyPressed)
    {
        _altKeyPressed = false;
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.S || e.SystemKey == Key.C)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    if (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
    {
        _altKeyPressed = true;
    }

    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

I tried it with e.Handled = true and e.Handled = false. This code gets called but changing the Handled Property brought no improvement.
I also tried the same approach by hooking up to the PreviewKeyDown EventHandler like this

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="_browser" PreviewKeyDown="_browser_OnPreviewKeyDown">
```

I am not showing the code for _browser_OnPreviewKeyDown because it is the same as in the OnPreviewKeyDown. Also this code gets called and has no change in behavior whether Handled is set to true or false.

Does anyone know how I can make the Chromium Control behave the same as an external browser in terms of Shortcuts?

**Update**

The browser did not have a keyboard handler. So I made one.

Please see the comments in OnKeyEvent to see where I am stuck at the moment.
Thank you

```
public class KeyboardHandler : IKeyboardHandler
{
    private bool _cefAltKeyPressed;
    public bool OnPreKeyEvent(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey, ref bool isKeyboardShortcut)
    {
        const int KEY_C = 67;
        const int KEY_S = 83;
        bool result = true;
        if (_cefAltKeyPressed)
        {
            if (windowsKeyCode == KEY_C || windowsKeyCode == KEY_S)
            {
                isKeyboardShortcut = true;
                result = false;
            }

            _cefAltKeyPressed = false;
        }

        if ((modifiers & CefEventFlags.AltDown) != 0 && type == KeyType.RawKeyDown)
        {
            _cefAltKeyPressed = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public bool OnKeyEvent(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey)
    {
        // With the code in OnPreKeyEvent, OnKeyEvent is only called, when Alt + S or Alt + C is pressed in the browser
        // So what am I supposed to do with this Event now?
        // I do not want to implement a search (Alt + S) or clear (Alt + C) functionality here, since that is part of the web site
        // I just want the website to be able to receive the Alt + S and Alt + C keystrokes and allow it to handle it
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  What are you expecting to happen and what is happening instead? You can look at the source to determine which key handlers are used.

Comment: The website performs a search with Alt + S and a Clear with Alt + C. The search and clear happen in an external Browser. Nothing happens in Chromium.

Comment: @amaitland: Please see the Update to my question. I don't know how to let the shortcut through to the web site. Can you help?

Comment: Use the WinForms version hosted in WPF using a WindowsFormsHost.